# Ключевое слово для запуска голосового опознования

Tags: c#

Пишу небольшую программку для управления голосом в музыкальном плеере.
Хочу сделать так, что бы программа начинала слушать команду после того, как я произнесу ключевое слово.
На данный момент имею такой вот код

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    static Label l;
    static NumericUpDown NUD;
    static bool Shutdown = false;
    static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {

        string playerpath = @"E:\Work\Programming\C#\SpeechRecognition\bin\Debug\player\AIMP.exe";

        if (e.Result.Text == "музыка" && e.Result.Confidence > (float)NUD.Value)
        {
            l.Text = "Плеер запущен";
            if (Shutdown)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(playerpath, "/PLAY"
                    //"/s /t 0"
                    );
            }
        }
        if (e.Result.Text == "стоп" && e.Result.Confidence > (float)NUD.Value)
        {
            l.Text = "Плеер остановлен";
            if (Shutdown)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(playerpath, "/STOP"
                    //"/s /t 0"
                    );
            }  
        }
        if(e.Result.Text == "громче" && e.Result.Confidence > (float)NUD.Value)
        {
            l.Text = "Добавляю громкость";
            if(Shutdown)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(playerpath, "/VOLUP");
            }
        }


        if (e.Result.Text == "тише" && e.Result.Confidence > (float)NUD.Value)
        {
            l.Text = "Убавляю громкость";
            if (Shutdown)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(playerpath, "/VOLDWN"
                    //"/s /t 0"
                    );
            }
        }
        if (e.Result.Text == "выключить плеер" && e.Result.Confidence > (float)NUD.Value)
        {
            l.Text = "Плеер выключен";
            if (Shutdown)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("TASKKILL", "/IM AIMP.EXE"
                    //"/s /t 0"
                    );
            }
        }


    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        l = label1;
        NUD = numericUpDown1;


        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-ru");
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);


        Choices numbers = new Choices();
        numbers.Add(new string[] { "громче" });
        numbers.Add(new string[] { "тише" });
        numbers.Add(new string[] { "музыка" });
        numbers.Add(new string[] {"стоп" });
        numbers.Add(new string[] { "выключить плеер" });

        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Culture = ci;
        gb.Append(numbers);


        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.LoadGrammar(g);

        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);


            Shutdown = true;
        Text = "Говорите";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Shutdown = true;
        Text = "Говорите";
        btnActive.Enabled = false;
    }

}
 }
```

Последние строчки кода которые связанны с кнопкой на форме это просто эксперимент с реагированием на нажатие кнопки а потом произношение команды.
Пробовал по мере знаний вставить функцию в часть кода, где происходит загрузка формы, но компилятор ругается на то, что нет описания события по опознаванию.
Оно в принципе понятно, поскольку параметров инициализации нет.